# Android Studio plugin for capture Strings

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I'm searching a plugin for Android Studio that help me catch the Strings in my APP, I don't use the recomendations of the Android and make my APP using Strings hardcoded.
How do you capture the Strings of codes of automatic way?

[I've searched in the google (web) but I can't find anyone]

Comment: What do you mean by "capture strings." Being able to search for them? Use them in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you are wondering how you can find all of your hardcoded strings, you can find them through Android Lint. In android studio go to Analyze -> Inspect Code. Then in the results expand Android Lint. Hardcoded text will be one of the items shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean searching your entire project for a specific string, you can use `command line`. Open the terminal window to the location of your project and

1. If you have git installed, use `git grep 'your keyword'`
2. If you are on a Linux or Unix machine, try using `grep -r "your keyword" .`

Both commands find all matches for your keyword in all files in the directory of the terminal window, and their subdirectories.